# Migrate class not registering properly

Tags: migrations

I am having trouble creating and registering migrate modules. At the moment, when I go to the UI screen, it says 'Class X no longer exists' (so, at least its being picked up) and wont show in the list of migrations on  the page. At the moment, I have only implemented one class and had this issue (when I figure this out, I will create everything else). Here is my code:

```
function migrate_rcmd_migrate_api() {
  $api = array(
    'api' => 2,
    'groups' => array(
      'Test' => array(
        'title' => t('Test Migrations'),
      ),
    ),
    'migrations' => array(
      'EventNode' => array(
        'class_name' => 'EventNodeMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
      'CareerNode' => array(
        'class_name' => 'CareerNodeMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
      'NodeRegistrationEntity' => array(
        'class_name' => 'NodeRegistrationEntityMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
      'JobPostingEntity' => array(
        'class_name' => 'JobPostingEntityMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
      'CoverLetterFileEntity' =>array(  //may only need one file entity migration class
        'class_name' => 'CoverLetterFileEntityMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
      'ResumeFileEntity' => array(
        'class_name' => 'ResumeFileEntityMigration',
        'group_name' => 'Test',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $api;
}
```

and

```
abstract class Test_Migration extends DynamicMigration {
  public function __construct() {
    // Always call the parent constructor first for basic setup
    parent::__construct();

    // With migrate_ui enabled, migration pages will indicate people involved in
    // the particular migration, with their role and contact info. We default the
    // list in the shared class; it can be overridden for specific migrations.
    $this->team = array(
      new MigrateTeamMember('Liz Taster', 'ltaster@example.com', t('Product Owner')),
      new MigrateTeamMember('Larry Brewer', 'lbrewer@example.com', t('Implementor')),
    );

    // Individual mappings in a migration can be linked to a ticket or issue
    // in an external tracking system. Define the URL pattern here in the shared
    // class with ':id:' representing the position of the issue number, then add
    // ->issueNumber(1234) to a mapping.
    $this->issuePattern = 'http://drupal.org/node/:id:';
  }
}

class EventNodeMigration extends Test_Migration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    //WE WILL NEED THIS
    //$this->dependencies = array('BeerTerm', 'BeerUser');

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'nid' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
          'alias' => 'n',
        )
      ),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );
    //example
    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
             ->select('node', 'n')
             ->fields('n', array('nid','vid','type','language','title','uid','status','created', 'changed','comment','promote','sticky','tnid','translate','uuid'))
              ->condition('type', 'events','=');
              //ADD JOINS TO FIELD TABLES HERE
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('events');

    $this->addSimpleMappings(array('nid','vid','type','language','title','uid','status','created', 'changed','comment','promote','sticky','tnid','translate','uuid'));
    //$this->addFieldMapping('title', 'page_title');
    //$this->addFieldMapping('body', 'page_body');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure:

1. your migrate_rcmd_migrate_api function is in the file migrate_rcmd.migrate.inc.
2. your Classes are included in .inc files defined in your modules .info file. See this documentation page on Migrate: https://drupal.org/node/1006982
3. Lastly in Migrate > 2.5 (i think thats the right version) migration auto discovery is now gone. You can use `drush migrate-register` to register your migrations and classes. See `drush help migrate-register` as needed.
4. when in doubt clear your caches: `drush cc all` to be sure the .inc files are registered in drupals code registry.

Comment: I think I've done all that. This is what I have in the .info file:
files[] = migrate_rcmd.migrate.inc
files[] = rcmd_migration.inc  -- the hook api is in the first file and the class in the second.
And actually, for #3, it says that automatic discovery is on

Comment: Thanks @tenken, 3. `drush mreg` did the trick for me

Answer (score -1):

Add this code your module hook_enable().

```
/**
* Implements hook_enable().
*/
function MODULENAME_enable() {
  Migration::registerMigration('MigrationClassName');
  $migration = Migration::getInstance('MigrationClassName');
  $result = $migration->processImport();
}
```